# Polynomials with range containing an arithmetic progression

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic

Can I find a polynomial in a second degree in two variables from the values of which can be found an infinite arithmetic progression?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try $$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$$ with a suitable dependence between $y$ and $x$.

> $y=x-1$.

Comment: If you succeed I would like to encourage you to post your solution in your own words as an answer. That way you get feedback from more people.

Comment: Perhaps even simpler is the polynomial $xy$.

Comment: LOL! A good one, @Gerry.